# Configure app to access directly with www.domain.com in Wildfly

Tags: deployment, wildfly

Good morning,

I have set up a server with Wildfly 13. Inside it I have deployed an application, and I have created a virtual host in the standalone.xml file to access this application from the URL "www.domain.com/app".

My question is, how do I configure wildfly so that if I access "www.domain.com" I go to the application I have in / app?

As a kind of redirection.

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2):

In your `WEB-INF` directory, create a file named `jboss-web.xml`.  In that file, have the contents be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web version="10.0"
           xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_10_0.xsd">

    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

In this example, the context root is `/` which is what you want.